# Why Lord Krishna didn't celebrate Deepavali?

Tags: krishna, yuga, festivals

Why Deepavali is not celebrated by Lord Krishna in Dwapara Yuga ? One of my friend asked me this tricky question. I didn't have an answer.

Moreover, Why there  is no mentioning of Ramayana incidents in Dwapara Yuga or isn't ?

Comment: I think you should split your question into two posts. "Why Lord Krishna didn't.." as one and "is there any incident of Ramayana mentioned in..." as another.

Comment: "Why there is no mentioning of Ramayana incidents in Dwapara Yuga" -- you mean in Bhaagavata or Mahaabhaarata instead of Dwapara..

Comment: There were incident related to Ramayana in Krishna's time. Such as, Raama did promise to Jamawanta that he will meet him in his next incarnation. And Krishna fullfill that promise by meeting Jamawanta. Krishna also met Hanumana and also gave order to Hanumana for his major contribution in Mahabharata war. Another one is, Hull used by Raama was later accepted as weapon by Balrama. There might be more, but only remember these for now.